# setting foreign key and primary key in gcp firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to GCP and NOSQL.

is it possible to have primary and foreign key in the GCP fire-store

Example: I have two table STUDENT and DEPARTMENT
table looks like below

### Department-table

dept-id(primary key)
deptname

## Student-table

dept-id(foreign key)
student-id
student name

can anybody please help in design this in GCP Fire-store?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by `foriegn key` and `primary key`

Comment: @dharmaraj ...in the above post department-id in DEPARTMENT Table (primary key) which will used identify each department and department-id- in the STUDENT table used as foreign key to identify to which department student belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Firestore won't support referential integrity.

It means that you can use any (subject to rules and conventions) names for fields, but the semantic and additional functionality is to be maintained by you, rather than by the system.

Comment: Do you have any example link  to design above scenario in fire-store?

Comment: I would suggest checking a description of a data model supported by Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model so you can assess pro and cons for a design you have in mind. If you definitely need the system build referential integrity - Firestore might not be a good choice. On the other hand, if you need both - the referential integrity is to be custom developed - i.e. https://dev.to/anishkny/---firestore-referential-integrity-via-triggers-kpb

Answer (score 0):

To a database, a key is the same as any UUID/randomID and can be shared and used between users, teams, admins, businesses, of all kinds. what matters is how that data is associated. Since Firestore is a noSQL database, there is no direct relational references, so one key cannot be equal to another without including secondary lookups.

In the same way you would define a user profile by an ID, you can create an empty document with a random ID to facilitate the ID of a team, or in this case the department. You can also utilize string combinations if you have a team and a sub-team, so long as at the point of the database request you have access to the team/department ID, you can use Regex to match a string comparison.

Example: `request.resource.data.name.matches('/^' + departmentID)`

To make a foreign key work with Security Rules or within the client, you must get the key that contains the data as the key should be the name of the document in question to streamline the request as you cannot perform queries or loop through data within Security Rules.

I great read on this subject, I highly suggest this article
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/a-list-of-firebase-firestore-security-rules-for-your-project-fe46cfaf8b2a

But my suggestion is to use a key that represents the department directly rather than using additional resource to have a foreign key and managing it.